# C#, java DataInputStream.readFully() equivalent

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, windows-store-apps

i`m writnig C# windows store application, an i recieve data via Sockets.
I want to know, is there are any C# quivalent method for java DataInptStream.ReadFully(). 
As written here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/datainputstream_readfully.htm

> method reads bytes from an input stream and allocates those into the
>   buffer array b.
>
> It blocks until the one of the below conditions occurs:
>   b.length bytes of input data are available.
>   Are there are any equivalent method in C#? That woul wait until length of bytes would de available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the text from the Java documentation is missing here, but as I understand it, you want a method that reads exactly the amount of bytes that the buffer is large, or fails with some kind of exception being thrown.

`BinaryReader.ReadBytes` (suggested by No One) does not behave like this:

> A byte array containing data read from the underlying stream. This
>   might be less than the number of bytes requested if the end of the
>   stream is reached.

As far as I know, there is no other method with equivalent behavior, but you could create it with an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static void ReadFully(this Stream stream, byte[] buffer)
{
    int offset = 0;
    int readBytes;
    do
    {
        // If you are using Socket directly instead of a Stream:
        //readBytes = socket.Receive(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset,
        //                           SocketFlags.None);

        readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset);
        offset += readBytes;
    } while (readBytes > 0 && offset < buffer.Length);

    if (offset < buffer.Length)
    {
        throw new EndOfStreamException();
    }
}
```

You can then use that extension method as if it was part of the `Stream` class, assuming you've imported the namespace it's defined in:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
myNetworkStream.ReadFully(buffer);
```